# Change default input text in Credit Memo - Refund total

Tags: magento2.4, creditmemo, refund

[image: Credit Memo]

I am new for Magento and I have to handle the website after old guys out. So, I think I can't make a refund because of template put $ in text box and return false for Validation in 'view/adminhtml/templates/order/creditmemo/create/totals/adjustments.phtml'. I want to know how to make '$' dissapear or any solution.

Comment: First confirm that file is override into any extension or theme for the changes?

Comment: yes, i didn't do anything

Comment: this seem to be same as my problem https://plumrocket.com/docs/magento-store-credit/v1/troubleshooting?utm_source=rss&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=magento-2-store-credit-extension-troubleshooting